# Data is updated without validation in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

For some reason data validation doesn't work. Although, if I add an alert statement after valid() method inside .click(), it will alert, which means that data is considered valid anyways. I tried different approaches including making actionbutton outside form in html file, but that didn't solve the problem. What else could that be? 
Currently there are no exceptions or errors.
JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#EmployeeForm").validate({
        rules: {
            TextBoxTitle: { maxlength: 4, required: true, validTitle: true },
            TextBoxFirstname: { maxlength: 25, required: true },
            TextBoxLastname: { maxlength: 25, required: true },
            TextBoxEmail: { maxlength: 40, required: true, email: true },
            TextBoxPhone: { maxlength: 15, required: true }
        },
        errorElement: "div",
        messages: {
            TextBoxTitle: {
                required: "required 1-4 chars.", maxlength: "required 1-4 chars.",
                validTitle: "Mr. Ms. Mrs. or Dr."
            },
            TextBoxFirstname: {
                required: "required 1-25 chars.", maxlength: "required 1-25 chars."
            },
            TextBoxLastname: {
                required: "required 1-25 chars.", maxlength: "required 1-25 chars."
            },
            TextBoxPhone: {
                required: "required 1-15 chars.", maxlength: "required 1-15 chars."
            },
            TextBoxEmail: {
                required: "required 1-40 chars.", maxlength: "required 1-40 chars.",
                email: "need vaild email format"
            }
        }
    });
    //custom validator
    $.validator.addMethod("validTitle", function (value, element) { // custom rule
        return this.optional(element) || (value == "Mr." || value == "Ms." || value == "Mrs." || value == "Dr.");
    }, "");

    //click event handler for the employee list
    $("#employeeList").click(function (e) {

        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var Id = e.target.parentNode.id;
        if (Id === 'employeeList' || Id === '')
            Id = e.target.id;

        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allemployees'));
        clearModalFields();

        //add, update or delete?
        if (Id === '0') {
            setupForAdd();
            $('#ImageHolder').html('');
        } else {
            setupForUpdate(Id, data);
        }
    });

    getAll('');

    $("#srch").keyup(function () {
        filterData();
    });

    function filterData() {
        filteredData = [];
        allData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allemployees'));

        $.each(allData, function (n, i) {
            if (~i.LastName.indexOf($("#srch").val())) {
                filteredData.push(i);
            }
        });
        buildEmployeeList(filteredData, false);
    }

    function loadDepartmentDDL(empdiv) {
        html = '';
        $('#ddlDivs').empty();
        var alldepartments = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('alldepartments'));
        $.each(alldepartments, function () {
            html += '<option value="' + this['Id'] + '">' + this['DepartmentName'] + '</option>';
        });
        $('#ddlDivs').append(html);
        $('#ddlDivs').val(empdiv);
    }

    $("#actionbutton").click(function () {
        if ($("#EmployeeForm").valid()) {
            if ($('#actionbutton').val() === 'Update') {
                update();
            } else {
                add();
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#lblstatus").text("fix existing problems");
            $("#lblstatus").css({ "color": "red" });
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('#deletebutton').click(function () {
        var deleteEmployee = confirm('Really delete this employee?');
        if (deleteEmployee) {
            _delete();
            return !deleteEmployee;
        }
        else {
            return deleteEmployee;
        }
    });

    function setupForUpdate(Id, data) {
        $('#actionbutton').val('Update');
        $('#modaltitle').html('<h4>Employee Update</h4>');
        $('#deletebutton').show();

        $.each(data, function (index, employee) {
            if (employee.Id === parseInt(Id)) {
                $('#TextBoxEmail').val(employee.Email);
                $('#TextBoxTitle').val(employee.Title);
                $('#TextBoxFirstname').val(employee.FirstName);
                $('#TextBoxLastname').val(employee.LastName);
                $('#TextBoxPhone').val(employee.Phoneno);
                $('#ImageHolder').html('<img height="120" width="110" src="data:image/png;base64,' + localStorage.getItem('StaffPicture') + '"/>');
                localStorage.setItem('Id', employee.Id);
                localStorage.setItem('DepartmentId', employee.DepartmentId);
                localStorage.setItem('Timer', employee.Timer);
                loadDepartmentDDL(employee.DepartmentId);
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#status').text('no employee found');
            }
        });
        $('#theModal').modal('toggle');
    }

    function setupForAdd() {
        clearModalFields();
        $('#actionbutton').val('Add');
        $('#modaltitle').html('<h4>Add New Employee</h4>');
        $('#deletebutton').hide();
        $('#theModal').modal('toggle');
    }

    //build the list
    function buildEmployeeList(data, allemployees) {
        $('#employeeList').empty();
        div = $('<div class="list-group"><div>' +
            '<span class="col-xs-4 h3">Title</span>' +
            '<span class="col-xs-4 h3">First</span>' +
            '<span class="col-xs-4 h3">Last</span>' +
            '</div>');
        div.appendTo($('#employeeList'))

        if (allemployees) {
            localStorage.setItem('allemployees', JSON.stringify(data));
        }

        btn = $('<button class="list-group-item" id="0">...Click to add employee</button>');
        btn.appendTo(div);

        $.each(data, function (index, emp) {
            btn = $('<button class="list-group-item" id="' + emp.Id + '">');
            btn.html(
                '<span class="col-xs-4" id="employeetitle' + emp.Id + '">' + emp.Title + '</span>' +
                '<span class="col-xs-4" id="employeefname' + emp.Id + '">' + emp.FirstName + '</span>' +
                '<span class="col-xs-4" id="employeelastname' + emp.Id + '">' + emp.LastName + '</span>');
            btn.appendTo(div);
        });


    }

    //get all employees
    function getAll(msg) {
        $('#status').text('Finding employee information...');

        ajaxCall('Get', 'api/employees', '')
            .done(function (data) {
                buildEmployeeList(data, true);
                if (msg === '')
                    $('#status').text('Employees Loaded');
                else
                    $('#status').text(msg + ' - Employees Loaded');
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                errorRoutine(jqXHR);
            });
        ajaxCall('Get', 'api/departments/', '')
            .done(function (data) {
                localStorage.setItem('alldepartments', JSON.stringify(data));
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error');
            });
    }

    function clearModalFields() {
        $('#TextBoxFirstname').val('');
        $('#TextBoxLastname').val('');
        $('#TextBoxEmail').val('');
        $('#TextBoxTitle').val('');
        $('#TextBoxPhone').val('');
        $('#modalStatus').text('');
        localStorage.removeItem('Id');
        localStorage.removeItem('DepartmentId');
        localStorage.removeItem('Timer');
        loadDepartmentDDL(-1);
    }

    function add() {
        emp = new Object();
        emp.Title = $("#TextBoxTitle").val();
        emp.FirstName = $("#TextBoxFirstname").val();
        emp.Lastname = $("#TextBoxLastname").val();
        emp.Phoneno = $("#TextBoxPhone").val();
        emp.Email = $("#TextBoxEmail").val();
        emp.DepartmentId = $("#ddlDivs").val();

        ajaxCall('post', 'api/employees/', emp)
            .done(function (data) {
                getAll(data);
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                errorRoutine(jqXHR);
            });
        $('#theModal').modal('toggle');
        return false;
    }

    function update() {
        emp = new Object();
        emp.Title = $("#TextBoxTitle").val();
        emp.FirstName = $("#TextBoxFirstname").val();
        emp.Lastname = $("#TextBoxLastname").val();
        emp.Phoneno = $("#TextBoxPhone").val();
        emp.Email = $("#TextBoxEmail").val();
        emp.Id = localStorage.getItem('Id');
        emp.DepartmentId = localStorage.getItem('DepartmentId');
        emp.DepartmentName = $('#ddlDivs').val();
        emp.Timer = localStorage.getItem('Timer');

        if (localStorage.getItem('StaffPicture')) {
            emp.Picture64 = localStorage.getItem('StaffPicture');
        }   

        ajaxCall('put', 'api/employees/', emp)
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#status").text(data);
                if (data.indexOf('not') == -1) {
                    $('#ImageHolder').html('<img height="120" width="110" src="data:image/png;base64,' + localStorage.getItem('StaffPicture') + '"/>')
                }
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                errorRoutine(jqXHR);
            });
        $('#theModal').modal('toggle');
        return false;

    }

    $("input:file").change(() => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var file = $('#fileUpload')[0].files[0];

        if (file) {
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        }

        reader.onload = function (readerEvt) {
            //get binary data then convert to encoded string
            var binaryString = reader.result;
            var encodedString = btoa(binaryString);
            localStorage.setItem('StaffPicture', encodedString);
        }
    });

    //delete employee
    function _delete() {
        ajaxCall('Delete', 'api/employees/' + localStorage.getItem('Id'), '')
            .done(function (data) {
                getAll(data);
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                errorRoutine(jqXHR);
            });
        $('#theModal').modal('toggle');
    }

    //cal ASP.NET WEB API server
    function ajaxCall(type, url, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: type,
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: true
        });
    }

    function errorRoutine(jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.responseJSON == null) {
            $('#status').text(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
        else {
            $('#status').text(jqXHR.responseJSON.Message);
        }

        if (jqXHR.responseJSON === null) {
            $("#lblstatus").text(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
        else {
            $("#lblstatus").text(jqXHR.responseJSON.Message);
        }
    }   //errrorRoutine

});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CRUD</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/employee.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #686868">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">#2</a>
            <div class="col-xs-2">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
                <li><a href="/employee.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/employeecrud.html" data-toggle="modal">CRUD</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-push-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 navbar navbar-brand" style="position:absolute; left:1200px;">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" id="srch" class="form-control form-md">
            </div>
            <div id="version" style="color:white; float:right;"><p>v2.0</p></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="padding-top:15%;">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center" id="status" style="font-weight:bold;"></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="employeeList"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form id="EmployeeForm" name="EmployeeModalForm" method="post" action="">
        <div class="modal fade" id="theModal" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                        <div id="modelTitle"></div>
                        <h4>Employee Update - v2.0</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                                Employee Information
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">Title:</div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8"><input type="text" placeholder="enter title" id="TextBoxTitle" class="form-control" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">First:</div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8"><input type="text" placeholder="enter first name" id="TextBoxFirstname" class="form-control" value="Joe" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">Surname:</div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8"><input type="text" placeholder="enter last name" id="TextBoxLastname" class="form-control" value="Blow" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">Phone#:</div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8"><input type="text" placeholder="enter phone" id="TextBoxPhone" class="form-control" value="(555)555-5555" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">Email:</div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8"><input type="text" placeholder="enter email" id="TextBoxEmail" class="form-control" value="jb@ss.com" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4"><strong>Department:</strong></div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                                        <select id="ddlDivs" name="ddlDivs" class="form-control"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">Picture:</div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8" id="ImageHolder" style="padding-top:2%;" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="col-xs-8"><input id="fileUpload" type="file" /></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="submit" value="Update" id="actionbutton" class="btn btn-default" style="position:absolute; right:100px; z-index:100; top:30px" /></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="button" value="Delete" id="deletebutton" class="btn btn-danger" style="position:absolute; top:30px; right:5px;" /></div>
                        <label class="col-xs-12 text-center row" id="lblstatus" style="padding-top:10px;"></label>
                        <div id="status" class="text-left" style="padding-top:5%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/employeecrud.js?newversion"></script> <!--Google Chrome does not load the newest version of the code. Adding unique string helps-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery validator works off of the name of the element not its id.

So for lets say for example on your email input you should add: `name="TextBoxEmail"`

Like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter email" id="TextBoxEmail" name="TextBoxEmail"
    class="form-control" value="jb@ss.com" />
```